# Most modern sci-fi with FTL that really is FTL

Tags: ftl-drive

It seems almost every form of faster than light travel in sci-fi is technically not **faster** than light, but rather a loophole - for example, a warp bubble, hyperspace, subspace, wormhole, jump drive, folding space etc.

What is the **most modern depiction** of craft or phenomena *travelling superluminally*, at or above *c*, without a 'loophole'?

Especially interested if there is a good explanation, and not simply ignoring, pre-dating or discounting theory (for example, a device that negates the mass of the object, thereby allowing it to reach *c* without increasing to infinite mass).

Comment: Of course. I think that was very common in the good old days. For instance, if I remember right, E. E. Smith's *Skylark* outran light without benefit of warp bubbles, wormholes, or the like.

Comment: Of note might be *Futurama* where, as I recall, they *raised* the speed of light. Not by technobabble, they just passed a law.

Comment: I'd love to learn of some more examples, apart from Skylark

Comment: This  is very broad. List of works *that contain x* areplicate off-topic

Comment: All FTL stories which were published before 1905..

Comment: I'm glad others are also interested in seeing more examples, but I do see the point that 'gimme lots of examples!' is quite broad. I've had a go editing it, hopefully it fits the standards now? Thanks.

Comment: Most modern???   Don't you mean the oldest?   That's the opposite of "most modern"

Comment: I'm also confused about what "not a loophole" means.   By all known physics, anything that goes FTL must be using a loophole.   Also, why is something like a warp bubble a loophole, but something like "rnegating your mass" is not a loophole.   This just makes no sense.

Comment: Most modern? That could change any day. Or every day.

Comment: I said most modern because as has been pointed out, 'oldest' would simply be 'anything before 1905'.

Comment: ThePopMachine by loophole I mean a process by which the object effectively moves from one location to the next in an interval of time shorter than sub-light travel would arrive, without actually travelling at or exceeding c. In my example negating mass would still have the object travelling at or exceeding c. Not to mention that by all known physics, a hyperdrive also isn't possible. This is scifi/fantasy we're talking.

Comment: Would the "we are not in the same dimension as Earth and here speed of light is not a limit" explanation also qualify? Piers Anthony wrote something like that in his "Mode" series in 1991

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **Skylark of Space** by E.E. “Doc” Smith, the speed of light is no limit at all. Einstein was simply wrong!  The ships in the Skylark series use simple acceleration,  and end up going very, very fast, hundreds of thousands of times the speed of light. Plus there's no relativistic time distortion.

> "About three hundred and fifty million miles," he stated. "Clear out of our solar system already, and from the distance covered he must have had a constant acceleration so as to approximate the velocity of light, and he is still going with full...."
>   "But nothing can possibly go that fast, Mart, it's impossible. How about Einstein's theory?"
>   "That is a theory, this measurement of distance is a fact, as you know from our tests."
>   "That's right. Another good theory gone to pot.

**Skylark of Space** was originally serialized in 1928, and first published in book form in 1946.

[image]

Here's  another:
In **Around A Distant Star** from 1904, by Jean Delaire, there's a ship which travels at 2000c, so they go out 2000 or so lightyears with a big telescope, to see Jesus teaching in Israel. Unfortunately this one doesn't have such awesome cover art.
[image]

Comment: Many of E E 'Doc' Smith's stories have FTL travel in normal space.  E.g. the "Lensman" stories have a drive system that allows travel at arbitrary speed by nullifying inertia; this isn't a loophole of the kind described in the question because per relatively if this could actually be done the result would be travel *at* light speed, but no faster.

Comment: For those so inclined you can get some of [E E Doc Smith's Skylark books for free on Project Gutenberg.org](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/9515).